# create the class to get the weather

Tags: javascript, class, asynchronous, promise

Help please, I create the main class to get the weather for four days, but the console throws an error - getCoordinates is not defined. What is the problem? Or the function init is wrong? I have the function getCoordinates, than get the city and return the latitude and longtitude, then it should be passed to the function get WeatherForeCast to get the weather and from this function the data passed into the function renderForeCastInfo to get the weather for four days. What is wrong?

```
class Weather {

    async getCoordinates() {
        //code
    }

    async getWeatherForecast(locationCoordinates) {
        //code
      }

    fahrenheitToCelsius(temp) {
        //code
    }

    renderForecastInfo(currently, daily) {
         //code
    }

    init() {
        getCoordinates().then(coords => {
            return getWeatherForecast(coords);
        }).then((forecast) => {
            const { currently, daily } = forecast;
            renderForecastInfo(currently, daily);
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to refer with `this` for member functions. Please see below code.

```js
class Weather {
    constructor(city) {
        this.city = city
    }

    async getCoordinates(city) {
         //code
    }

    async getWeatherForecast(locationCoordinates) {
         //code
      }

    fahrenheitToCelsius(temp) {
         //code
    }

    renderForecastInfo(currently, daily) {
         //code
    }

    init() {
    
        this.getCoordinates().then(coords => {
            return this.getWeatherForecast(coords);
        }).then((forecast) => {
            const { currently, daily } = forecast;
            this.renderForecastInfo(currently, daily);
        });
    }
}
const w1= new Weather();
w1.init();
```

Comment: the is error, when I write const w1= new Weather('Paris'); https://api.opencagedata.com/geocode/v1/json?q=undefined&key=08e017c5ff6741f78326386409566648&pretty=1&no_annotations=1&language=en - in url city is undefined

Comment: URL part `const url = `https://api.opencagedata.com/geocode/v1/json?q=${this.city}&key=08e017c5ff6741f78326386409566648&pretty=1&no_annotations=1&language=en`;`

Comment: find another problem getWeatherForecast is not defined

Comment: I have edited the code to have the fix, please check now.

Comment: @ameli Glad it worked, if possible please mark this as answer, other may find it useful.

Comment: can you please check my question again? I updated my code. I create a child class. But in child Class i have an error this.makeRandom(...).then is not a function. Please, can you help me?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220274/discussion-between-asutosh-and-ameli).

Comment: The makeRandom does not return a promise so then won't be available